# C#: poor performance when manipulating strings from big txt files

Tags: c#, .net, string

I've got big txt file in which I have to find some records and rewrite them to other file.

I made my method like this:

```
    private ArrayList getRelatingObjects(string[] Ob, string Tab)
    {
        ArrayList rel = new ArrayList();

        foreach (string[] s in SO)
        {
            foreach (string x in s)
            {
               if (x.Length > 0)
               {
                   if (x[0].Equals('W'))
                   {
                       string xTemp = x.Substring(x.IndexOf(',') + 1);
                       xTemp = xTemp.Substring(xTemp.IndexOf(',') + 1);
                       xTemp = xTemp.Substring(xTemp.IndexOf(',') + 1).Replace(";", "");

                       string obTemp = Ob[0].Substring(Ob[0].IndexOf(',', 3) + 1);
                       obTemp = obTemp.Substring(obTemp.IndexOf(',') + 1);
                       obTemp = obTemp.Substring(0, obTemp.IndexOf(','));

                       if (xTemp.Equals(obTemp) && (x.Substring(x.IndexOf(',', 3) + 1).Contains(Tab)))
                       {
                           if (!rel.Contains(s) && !s[0].Substring(x.IndexOf(',', 3) + 1).Contains("G5ZMN"))
                           {
                               rel.Add(s);
                           }
                       }
                   }
                }
            }
        }
        return rel;
    }
```

SO is ArrayList where I put arrays of my records (there are like arrays from DB). 
Here I need to find relating object to my chosen object.

The problem is when I use files like 2MB it's not enough fast. (I already replaced Splits functions with Substrings (they are faster than remove I checked it).

But my performance is not still enough.

Do you have some idea how can I do it faster? 
Most of CPU power I lose on SubStrings and replace but I still dunno if I can do it faster.

Comment: regular expressions can improve performance.

Comment: I don't know how can I use regex here.

Comment: could you post an example of the text how it looks like and how it should be transformed?

Comment: RD,,G5DOK,280404_2_DZK_25555,,11;
And I need only 280404_2_DZK_25555

OR 
WG,G5ROBR,G5O_OBR,280404_2_93;
And I need G50_OBR and 280404_2_93

Comment: Could you copy more of the text into something like pastebin? I can help you with the regex then. It will definetly speed up the performance to a fraction of what its now

Comment: It looks like you read the whole file into memory as a string array and then go though that. Have you considered using streaming, so you dont need to read the whole file, but just the line you currently analyse ?

Comment: No, because I always have to analyse whole file.

Comment: @RadosławKunecki - unless you need to compare data across multiple lines in your file, reading in the whole file in memory could potentially degrade performance as well. As Ryu suggests, as long as you only have to look at one line at a time (as your sample suggests) read the file line by line.

Comment: How many results does "rel" hold approximately?

Comment: It depends, this method is lunched multiple time (for different Tabs)

Comment: Well, you didn't really answer my question. The rel.Contains() check is O(n) every time which is pretty expensive. You can switch it to HashSet. However, if the rel holds only ~5 results, it won't probably help you.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a 100% solution because you i have no exactly description of the elements you want to receive

```
 private IEnumerable<string> ReadData(string filepath)
 {
   var res = new List<string>( );
   var fileInfo = new FileInfo( filepath );

   if( !fileInfo.Exists )
   {
     throw new ArgumentException( "No file exist with the path " + filepath,
                                  "filepath" );
   }

   var fileStream = fileInfo.Open( FileMode.Open,
                                   FileAccess.Read );
   var file = new StreamReader( fileStream,
                                Encoding.UTF8 );
   string lineOfText;
   while( ( lineOfText = file.ReadLine( ) ) != null )
   {
     var pattern = new Regex( @"^[\w]{2},[\w]{0,},[\w]{1,},([\w]{1,})(?:,[\w]{0,},[\w]{1,}){0,1};$");

     var match = pattern.Match( lineOfText );
     if( match.Success )
     {
       res.Add( match.Groups[ 0 ].Value );
     }
     else
     {
       // Handle lines with wrong format
     }
   }

  return res;
}
```

To explain the pattern:

^ (anchor to start of string)
Any character in "\w"
Exactly 2 times
,
Any character in "\w"
At least 0 times
,
Any character in "\w"
At least 1 times
,
Capture => Element for the result
  Any character in "\w"
  At least 1 times
End Capture
Non-capturing Group
  ,
  Any character in "\w"
  At least 0 times
  ,
  Any character in "\w"
  At least 1 times
End Capture
At least 0, but not more than 1 times
;$ (anchor to end of string)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, strings are immutable in C#. Each time you call the substring or replace method you create a new string. Try using [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) instead.

Secondly you are loading a big chunk of strings directly into memory, consider using something like the [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.streamreader) class

Finally, you should probably use [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) for pattern matching.